# Moving from Ubuntu to CentOS

Tags: ubuntu, centos, migration

Right now I have my own server (in my house actually) that hosts my website using Ubuntu. For obvious reasons I'm planning on switching to a VPS soon. I've read that CentOS is a better choice over Ubuntu for the VPS OS. So my question is, how difficult will it be to migrate over from one OS to the other? Here's a list of some of the packages I depend on:

- Webmin
- Gitolite
- ZNC
- ircd-hybrid and hybserv
- awstats

Will all of these packages be compatible with CentOS? What about all my config files? Will I have to edit them from scratch, or can I simply transfer them from one server to another?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the following two rpms into your CentOS, install it and then do a

```
yum search package_name
```

http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm

http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.i386.rpm

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed them with apt/aptitude on Ubuntu you should check the config files in CentOS. everything else should work fine.

And if you have installed everything from source—there shouldn't be any problem at all.